# How do I make OneDrive put fail, when the item already exists?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), I can use http PUT to create a OneDrive item.
For example, the uri below creates a testfile.txt at my root:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/testfile.txt:/content
```

Now, I would like the PUT to fail, if the file already exists, and the general documentation on OneDrive items, https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm#optional-query-string-parameters, states how to specify conflict behavior - if I read it correctly, like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/testfile.txt:/content?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=fail
```

However, the PUT still successfully overwrites the existing 'testfile.txt'.

Can anyone help me write a PUT query so that it fails in case the item already exists?
Is that even supported by OneDrive?
Do I need to go to the beta version of Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession) this should be specified within request body, not as a query parameter:

```
{
    "item": {
        "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "fail"
    }
}
```

This is also only supported in the Resumable Upload" scenario as the request body for a direct upload is the file itself. In general, the guidance is to always use resumable uploads where possible. Direct uploads are limited to files less than 4MB which makes it unsuitable for most scenarios.

It is also worth noting that the documentation you referenced is for the standalone OneDrive API. While this is *very* similar to Graph's implementation, they are not entirely interchangeable. The [Microsoft Graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) is the only authoritative source for Graph information.

Comment: The docs on dev.onedrive.com do actually describe calling via Microsoft Graph and should be considered authoritative for how to use OneDrive via Microsoft Graph. There is a separate document that describes the differences between Microsoft Graph and the OneDrive API, but the contents of all of the documentation is focused on MS Graph.

Comment: @Marc LaFleur, the first link is broken